# files with same name in different folders

Tags: linux, bash, file, shell, scripting

I am looking for a command line that can do some operations on two files that have the same names but in different folders.

for example if

- folder `A` contains files `1.txt`, `2.txt`, `3.txt`, …
- folder `B` contains files `1.txt`, `2.txt`, `3.txt`, …

I would like to concatenate the two files `A/1.txt` and `B/1.txt`, and `A/2.txt` and `B/2.txt`, …

I'm looking for a shell command to do that:

```
if file name in A is equal the file name in B then: 
    cat A/1.txt B/1.txt
end if
```

for all files in folders `A` and `B`, if only names are matched.

Comment: Where do you want the output of the `cat` to go? Your example goes to `stdout` but I wasn't sure if that's your intention. Or do you have a 3rd file for each pair?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this to get the files which have names in common:

```
cd dir1
find . -type f | sort > /tmp/dir1.txt
cd dir2
find . -type f | sort > /tmp/dir2.txt
comm -12 /tmp/dir1.txt /tmp/dir2.txt
```

Then use a loop to do whatever you need:

```
for filename in "$(comm -12 /tmp/dir1.txt /tmp/dir2.txt)"; do
    cat "dir1/$filename"
    cat "dir2/$filename"
done
```

Comment: You hardly need the temporary files or `comm`. Just loop over files in `dir1` and skip the ones which are not also in `dir2`.

Answer (score 6):

For simple things maybe will be enough the next syntax:

```
cat ./**/1.txt
```

or you can simply write

```
cat ./{A,B,C}/1.txt
```

e.g.

```
$ mkdir -p A C B/BB
$ touch ./{A,B,B/BB,C}/1.txt
$ touch ./{A,B,C}/2.txt
```

gives

```
./A/1.txt
./A/2.txt
./B/1.txt
./B/2.txt
./B/BB/1.txt
./C/1.txt
./C/2.txt
```

and

```
echo ./**/1.txt
```

returns

```
./A/1.txt ./B/1.txt ./B/BB/1.txt ./C/1.txt
```

so

```
cat ./**/1.txt
```

will run the `cat` with the above arguments... or,

```
echo ./{A,B,C}/1.txt
```

will print

```
./A/1.txt ./B/1.txt ./C/1.txt #now, without the B/BB/1.txt
```

and so on...

Answer (score 4):

Will loop through all files in folder `A`, and if a file in `B` with same name exists, will `cat` both:

```
for fA in A/*; do
    fB=B/${f##*/}
    [[ -f $fA && -f $fB ]] && cat "$fA" "$fB"
done
```

Pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), except the `cat` part, of course.